# Как восстановить напоминания в AlarmManager для моего приложения после перезагрузки устройства без WakefulBroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Я знаю похожий вопрос уже был, но решение за два года сильно устарело. 
Теперь WakefulBroadcastReceiver устарел и вместо него рекомендуют использовать JobService. Но как использовать именно в моём случае JobService я не понимаю. Поэтому вопрос от оригинального отличается контекстом.

Моё приложение должно напоминать пользователю о начале рабочего дня. Каждую ночь приложение само должно в 0:00 часов загружать с сервера расписание работы пользователя и "заводить будильник" на начало рабочего дня (например на 8 утра). При этом каждый раз когда пользователь запускает приложение происходит та же синхронизация расписания с сервером (на случай если произошли какие-то изменения).

И всё бы ничего, но если пользователь перезагрузил устройство, то задачи AlarmManager очищаются. И мне нужно чтобы после перезагрузки моё приложение повторно устанавливало напоминания для AlarmManager.

Ранее как я понимаю решением было использовать WakefulBroadcastReceiver, который запускался сразу после перезагрузки системы. Но теперь он устарел. Погуглив я узнал, что вместо него теперь рекомендуется использовать JobService. Но во всех примерах рассматриваются совершенно другие ситуации (например ожидание появляения вайфая и т.п.).

Как можно применить JobService к моей ситуации? Или какое есть ещё решение для повторного добавления задач в AlarmManager после перезагрузки девайса?

Comment: много текста для простого вопроса, создайте BroadcastReceiver с  android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED и в нем перезапускайте задачи с AlarmManager

Comment: Не думал что всё так просто) Но у меня это сработало только когда я в настройках приложения включил автозапуск. Есть ли какая-то возможность сразу разрешить автозапуск приложения (ну например как запрос разрешения на использования камеры или внутренней памяти)?

Comment: Оказалось, что не на всех устройствах по-умолчанию отключён автозапуск приложения. Это касается похоже только сяоми.

Comment: подтверждаю ...